# How to check two strings for difference in casing only?

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

Following pairs of string are possible. Now my goal is to detect only the casing difference in the first example:

1. "abC","abc"
2. "abc","abc"
3. „abDef","abc"

My approach would be first to compare the strings with ignorecase = true in C#:

`String.Compare(string1, string2, true)` returns 0 for 1.+2. and returns 1 for the 3. possibility

So checking for 0 as result I can narrow down my results to two possibilities which I check now with ignorecase = false:

`String.Compare(string1, string2, false)`

So checking now for 0 would give me the right result. Is there any better solution to achieve this in one compare step?

Comment: Do you not like to use `String.Compare`? What about `String.Equals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0) exists to cover the reverse scenario you have suggested, but in the context of sorting scenarios, you can use it for equality using `== 0` or inequality  `!=0`

[String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0) performs the same evaluation logic as String.Compare, but specifically for equality scenarios.

The issue in your case of detecting *in*-equality based only on *casing* means that you will have to do it in two checks, otherwise the strings not equalling at all would return a false negative response.

The following options come to mind:

```
public static bool IsSimilarButDifferentCase(string input1, string input2)
{
    // satisfy the first criteria
    if (input1.Equals(intput2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // check that it is now NOT the same
        return !input1.Equals(intput2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also do the following inline by converting to the lower (or upper case) and using the comparison operators directly:

```
input1.ToLower() == input2.ToLower() && input1 != input2
```

*Feel free to us different culture overloads or variations to all the above as your business needs dictate.*